# How to open email client without sending an email using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to either open the default email client or a list of available email clients when a user presses a button. When the user chooses which client to use, the user should be redirected to the inbox of the email app. Is this possible using Android intents?

I was only able to find solutions to launch email when actually creating an email.

Comment: So you just want to give option to open mail app? that's all?

Comment: @Ranjan Yes, that is all.

Comment: Based on some testing we did on a recent project, IMHO there is no reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for this, you need to create a custom chooser, for example, you can create a `BottomSheetDialog` that has a `RecyclerView`  of `ResolveInfo` items

get the packages that able to send email

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getActivity().getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
```

and create your items you can get the icon of the applications 
onbind of your items

```
   set(ResolveInfo info, int pos) {
                PackageManager pm = App.getInstance().getPackageManager();
                appName.setText(info.activityInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                appIcon.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm));
}
```

and on click of the item in recycler view

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Comment: This seems to create a new email message, which I do not want. I only want to open the email application.

Comment: @mrfonnes this open the application itself not the create email 
the `getLaunchIntentForPackage` will do that for you .. did you test it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I only tested the first part of the code (intent) which indicated the new email message. I'll test the remaining.

Comment: the first `sendIntent` is to get the packages that have the send to action 
then use `Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage` 
to lunch that package since the first when you specify an action but the second intent only launches the app.